# Ajax Request Get Different Response Value From PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax request code

```
$("#input_form").on("your change event",function(e){
        if(changeTimer !== false) clearTimeout(changeTimer);
        changeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'exchanger',
        data: $('#depo').serialize(), 
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#result").addClass('deposit-input-loading');
        }
    }).done(function(t) {
        data = $.parseJSON(t);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#result").removeClass('deposit-input-loading');
            $("#ex_limit").html('min: '+data.value);
            $("#received_amount").val(data.receive_amount);
        }, 1000);
    })
            changeTimer = false;
        },50);
});
```

But error in after done function in ajax request.
my PHP file code was like this

```
$rate = $API->getRate($send, $received, $amount);
$limits = $API->getLimits($send, $received);
echo json_encode($rate);
echo json_encode($limits);
```

the echo json_encode show different array
How to get the response from different json_encode and show in ajax request?

Comment: You can not just output the result of two `json_encode` calls after another, and expect the result to be valid JSON again. Return both values inside _one_ data object, like f.e. `echo json_encode('rate' => $rate, 'limits' => $limits);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this into your PHP File:

```
$rate = $API->getRate($send, $received, $amount);
$limits = $API->getLimits($send, $received);
$array = array('rate' => $rate, 'limits' => $limits); 
echo json_encode($array); exit;
```

Then check your data variable in ajax done method.

Comment: and how to call it within the ajax jquery?

Comment: like this one? $("#ex_limit").html(data.rate.value);

Comment: You will have to do this inside your ajax response
var response = JSON.parse(response);
then you can get rate by doing response.rate

Comment: In your case
var data = JSON.parse(data); 
then do 
$("#ex_limit").html(data.rate.value);